# Android Studio -Unable to inflate view tag without class attribute

Tags: android, xml, rendering

When I enter a view tag into my xml code I get a Rendering Problem that says: "Unable to inflate view tag without class attribute". How can I fix this ?

```
    <view
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray">
    </view>
```

When I remove this code it renders fine.

Comment: it is `View` with capital `V`

Comment: it works for me.just change view tag by capital [View]

Answer (score 57, accepted):

As mentioned in comment by Blackbelt, update `view` to `View`:

```
<View
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray">
</View>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<View
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray">
</View>
```

You must use `View` Instead `view`.

Comment: How is your answer unique from the accepted answer?