# adding view tag in xml shows the error: Unable to inflate view tag without class attribute

Tags: android, xml, tags, android-view

A part of my `xml` you can see, the error is from `<view/>` tag. When I delete one of the view, it will be ok. I also have used it but it did not appear the error. So what is the reason of it?
Thanks!

```
<view
   android:layout_width="1dp"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="@color/colorPopul">
</view>
```

Comment: where is the view tag?

Answer (score 2):

Possible duplicate of [Android Studio -Unable to inflate view tag without class attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40047133/android-studio-unable-to-inflate-view-tag-without-class-attribute).

Change the **view** to **View**.

```
<View
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPopul" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I was Struggling a lot with this error and at the end i find it's solution and it's really simple

```
<View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Comment: your answer is confusing as you changed the `layout_width` property from `1dp` to `match_parent` although that is not necessary

Comment: You can customize width and height according to your need , it's just for example , definitely you can set it to 1 dp as well. Thanks!